# Virgin Atmega32u4 USB ISP initialization failure

Tags: atmel, atmega32u4

I custom made my own PCB to use Atmega32u4.
It's really a clone of PJRC's Teensy 2.0.
Unfortunately I cannot initialize any of my Atmel Store purchased Atmega32u4 using USBTinyISP. The schematic is below:
[image]

And the exact message is

> "avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1"

- I tried 3 MCUs. All the same problem.
- I have omitted all the by-pass capacitors, including UCAP.
- I tried with and without any of the XTAL components installed.
- Connections between my ISP and the PCB are checked.

Any pointer will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have omitted all the by-pass capacitors, including UCAP.

The MCUs are *not* expected to work without bypass caps, there is at least one bypass cap missing. UCAP is also not connected properly in the schematic and would work as an antenna instead.

Comment: Great!  I'm glad it's obvious. I thought by caps were stability purpose only. So I thought I could at least get it recognized by the programmer. Also, what is wrong with my UCAP connection? The data sheet says it should be simply connected to a capacitor.

Comment: Oh I see I screwed up with the UCAP connection. Don't know how it happened:(